# changing package from "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" To "Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets"

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, azure-keyvault

I am using nuget `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault` and I am using below code for asp.net core 3.1 in `Program.cs`,

I am doing custom certificate authentication for azure keyVault. Also using custom secret management.

```
   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions
                    {
                        Vault = "key vault url",
                        ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                        //authenticate with custom certificate
                        Client = new KeyVaultClient(CustomCertificateAuthenticationCallback),
                        Manager = new CustomKeyVaultSecretManager()
                    });
                }
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

The package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault` is deprecated and I have uninstalled this package and installed the updated one `Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets`. After switching to this package I am NOT able to figure our how to use `custom` validation and how to pass `keyvault url`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try [`SecretClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient?view=azure-dotnet) method, and refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1) about Azure Key Vault Configuration Provider.

```
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();
                var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
                                                         new DefaultAzureCredential());
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());


            }
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

SecretClient doesn't support `AuthenticationCallback`(*Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback*).

If you would like to authenticate with certificate, you could new [TokenCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet) with *Azure.Identity.ClientCertificateCredential*.

```
X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2(certPath, pfxpassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
                                            new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantID, clientID, cer);
```

Comment: ok, Thanks. How to CustomCertificateAuthenticationCallback?

Comment: I edit my reply about authenticating with certificate. Try the code with ClientCertificateCredential().

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to also keep the "ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)," ?

Answer (score 3):

As the suggestion in the Accepted Answer does not have the ReloadInterval property, here is the suggestion to keep all properties as in the original code, while using the new package:

```
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                    new Uri($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
                    new DefaultAzureCredential(),
                    new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
                    {
                        Manager = new KeyVaultSecretManager(),
                        ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
                    }
                 );
            }
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```